# Is there a way to bind an arrays child objects?

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-phone-7, binding, sorting

I current have some objects in an array like this `node[1][1]`, there are multiple child objects/variables for each parent eg.. `node[1][2]`, `node[1][3]` etc..

There are also multiple parent objetcs eg.. `node[2][1]`, `node[3][1]`  etc..

What I want to do is bind/Display all child objects in a listbox from all parents

eg..`listBox1.itemsource = node[All][1];`

I have done some research but can't find any way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whomever Down voted, please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution for this. Using foreach and then if statement to find and display specfic element

Examples Code *********************************

```
// statements_foreach_arrays.cs
// Using foreach with arrays
using System;
class MainClass 
{
   public static void Main() 
   {
      int odd = 0, even = 0;
      int[] arr = new int [] {0,1,2,5,7,8,11};

      foreach (int i in arr) 
      {
         if (i%2 == 0)  
            even++;      
         else 
            odd++;         
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Found {0} Odd Numbers, and {1} Even Numbers.",
                        odd, even) ;
   }
}
```

[Using foreach with Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288254%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)